# Exporting TO SVG in Adobe Illustrator results in different fonts when viewed on the Web

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to export a logo from Adobe Illustrator to SVG for the Web.  I followed the steps and properly exported the SVG file.  Loaded it and published the page.  It looks fine on my Development PC; however, when I tried to view the same page on another PC, some of the fonts have changed and does not display properly.  How do I make sure the fonts are available in the SVG file for publication and display everywhere?

Comment: You can just convert all the fonts into outlines in your SVG file. It will a classic robust solution. No fonts no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

The less fonts the less problems.